# Obtener valor de PATH en CMD (Variable de entorno)

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, registro-windows

¿Hay alguna manera de obtener el valor de la variable de entorno PATH a través del símbolo del sistema?

Por ejemplo:

```
REG QUERY HKCU\Environment /v PATH
```

Me arroja el valor de la variable PATH del usuario actual (también se puede hacer con la del sistema escribiendo una ruta diferente, pero solamente necesito la de usuario), pero junto con ello también me indica el nombre de la variable y de que tipo es (por defecto viene en REG_SZ pero también puede ser REG_SZ_EXPAND).

Lo que quiero hacer es guardar el valor de PATH en alguna variable para después hacer operaciones ella, por ejemplo, una concatenación de cadenas, etcétera.

***Nota Importante:*** No puedo hacer algo como:
    set x=%path%
porque esto combina el valor de PATH del usuario con el del sistema, y solamente necesito el valor de PATH del usuario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el comando que pones efectivamente arroja el PATH del usuario actual, entonces simplemente tienes que tomar su valor de la salida del comando `REG QUERY`, que se encuentra en el tercer elemento separado por espacios, mediante un comando `FOR /F`:

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('REG QUERY HKCU\Environment /v PATH') do set "x=%%a"

echo PATH del usuario: "%x%"
```

Comment: Vaya! Si que hace lo que quiero, solamente que hay un problema, hay una ruta dentro del valor PATH que tiene un espacio `;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;`, entonces ya no devuelve las rutas que siguen después de esta debido a que se corta por el limite de `tokens=3`. ¿Hay alguna manera de resolver esto?

Comment: Cambia `tokens=3` por `tokens=2*` y cambia `set "x=%%a"` por `set "x=%%b"`

Answer (score 2):

%HOMEPATH% almacena la ruta completa para la carpeta por default del usuario; si también requieres la unidad está en %HOMEDRIVE%.

Si necesitas una lista de variables: **https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html**

Comment: Puedes usar estas dos formas:

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar estas dos formas:

```
echo %PATH&


SET PATH
```

El inconveniente de la última es que inicia con PATH=

Answer (score 1):

No existe una variable de entorno que puedas acceder desde el simbolo de sistema que te muestre solo la variable de entorno PATH asignada para el usuario.

Como referencia de los diferentes ámbitos de las variables de entorno se puede visualizar el editor directamente con el siguiente comando:

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```